# How to declare an unsigned 32-bit integer?

Tags: powershell, 32-bit, unsigned-integer

Is there a way to declare a 32-bit unsigned integer in PowerShell?

I'm trying to add an unsigned (begin with `0xf`) i.e. `0xff000000 + 0xAA`, but it turned out to be a negative number whereas I want it to be `0xff0000AA`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

0xff00000AA is too large for a 32 bit unsigned integer, use uint64

```
PS> [uint64]0xff00000AA
68451041450
```

Comment: This does not answer the question _actually_ asked, i.e., how to declare an unsigned 32-bit integer, with the remainder of the text implying the high bit is set. The answer provided by Pencho _does_ provide a means to do this. Given the question asked, it seems reasonable to assume the example provided just has more hex digits than intended and _not_ that it is "too large" for a 32 bit integer (signed or otherwise).

Comment: `0xff000000 + 0xAA = 0xff0000AA`, not `0xff00000AA`. All of them fit in uint32

Answer (score 15):

The code from the currently accepted answer causes the following error on my system:

[image: error message]

This is because PowerShell always tries to convert hex values to int first so even if you cast to `uint64`, the environment will complain if the number has a negative int value. You can see this from the following example:

```
PS C:\> [uint64] (-1)
Cannot convert value "-1" to type "System.UInt64". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64."
At line:1 char:26
+ Invoke-Expression $ENUS; [uint64] (-1)
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible
```

You need to cast the string representation of the number to `uint64` to avoid this:

```
[uint64]"0xff000000" + [uint64]"0xAA"
```

Comment: I do not get the error you described, and the answer @Shay gave works just fine for me. Using 64bit PSv2.
However, just entering `0xff00000AA` does auto-convert to `68451041450` without the need for casting.

Comment: @SpellingD: The difference is Pencho used `0xFF0000AA` (four zeros) to get a signed `Int32` negative value (which fails to convert to an unsigned value), where the question uses `0xFF00000AA` (five zeros) to get a signed `Int64` positive value (which converts successfully).

Comment: Do not use images to post code or errors. Copy them into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to cast to `[uint32]` from a `long` literal (with the `L` suffix). You don't need to do the math in `[uint64]` or cast from a string

```powershell
[uint32]0xff000000L + 0xAA
```

In PowerShell 6.2 [a series of new suffixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-6) have been added including a `u` suffix fof `uint32` so this can be done even simpler

```powershell
0xff000000u + 0xAA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant `0xff0000AA` since, as others have mentioned, `0xff00000AA` is an overflow.

The easiest way to do this is to convert the value from a string.  You can either use `System.Convert`:

```
[System.Convert]::ToUInt32('0xff0000AA',16)
[System.Convert]::ToUInt32('ff0000AA',16)
```

Or just try to cast the string, but in this case you need to prepend the `0x`:

```
[uint32]'0xff0000AA'
```

If, on the other hand, you really *did* want to know the 32-bit unsigned integer portion of the 64-bit number `0xff00000aa', then you could do this:

```
[System.Convert]::ToUInt32([System.Convert]::ToString(0xff00000AA -band ([uint32]::MaxValue),16),16)
```